# On changing the order of summation between a finite sum and an infinite sum.

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-series

Suppose that for every $j=1,...,t$ we have a convergent series of complex numbers $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_j^m$. My question is:

> Is it true in general that $$\sum_{j=1}^t\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_j^m\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^ta_j^m\right)$$
>   If not, under which extra conditions this can be true?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always true because limits and finite sums commute.

$$\sum_{j=1}^t\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_j^m= \sum_{j=1}^t\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=0}^n a_j^m = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^t\sum_{m=0}^{n}a_j^m = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^ta_j^m = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^ta_j^m$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general for a technical reason, the expanded limit may not exist.
For example, $\sum_n (2^n-2^n) = 0$ but $\sum_n 2^n -\sum_n 2^n$ doesn't make sense.

If $\sum_n a_n, \sum_n b_n$ are convergent, then we have
$\sum_n (a_n+b_n) = \sum_n a_n + \sum_n b_n$ because the
finite sums are interchangeable and one can then take limits.

Hence it is true for a finite collection of summations.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the connection of your answer with my question. Could you explain it better?

Comment: Well, you only need to prove it for $t=2$ and then it easily generalises. Also, it is true for any convergent sequences, not just those of the form $a_i^m$.

Comment: No, I meant I didn't get your argument, what "the expanded limit may not exist" means? Moreover your answer seems to be on contrast with the one of mechanodroid

Comment: I have changed my illustration to match your setup. It doesn't apply since you have assumed convergence, it is just to point out that the swapping can fail if the sequences are not convergent. I am not sure I see the contrast with the other answer, they are essentially the same except in generality.